# Convergence in probability of non-negative random variable and expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $\mathbb E X$ exists and $X_n : X_n$ non-negative and $X_n \to^P X$ . How to show, that $\mathbb E X_n \to \mathbb E X \iff \mathbb E |X_n - X| \to 0$?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the wording, can you state the assumptions and then, given those assumptions, what you are trying to prove?  (I'm not sure what "then and only when" means...do you mean an "if and only if"...also, I'm not sure how the second sentence relates to the first.)

Comment: I see.  Can you show one direction?  It is easier to show $E[|X_n-X|]\rightarrow 0 \implies E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X]$.

Comment: I tried to show it but I can't do it without hint, so, I need one.

Comment: Can you write $X_n \leq ...$ with the right-hand-side depending on $X$ and $|X_n-X|$?